# Monitor all the queriers executed by my website

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, phpmyadmin

I am extending the functionalities of one plugin. For the sake for this I would really like to know if there is anyway I could view all the queries that are done to my database live??

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) will show all queries done on a single page.

Also there is the [`query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query/) filter that you could use to log queries as they are made.

Comment: The plugin Query Monitor for some reasons shows only queries of type select. No insert no update and /or delete.... no idea why

The query is not good explaind and I really dont know how and where to use it...